# Java Instrumentation

Tags: java, instrumentation

I have a javaagent that prints out names of all classes that get loaded, and their source (where they are from).

```
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class redefiningClass, ProtectionDomain domain, byte[] bytes) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        System.out.print("Loading class: " + className + "\t");
        if (domain != null) {
          final CodeSource cs = domain.getCodeSource();
          if (cs != null) {
            System.out.println(cs.getLocation());
          }
        }
        System.out.println();
        return bytes;
    }
```

For some classes, it prints out "null" (meaning cs.getLocation() is null). Why is this, and is there anyway to see where those classes are from? Note, I am not doing this on my own Java app, so I have no knowledge of any custom ClassLoaders it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Jetty 7.0.0RC4](http://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/7.0.0.RC4/xref/org/eclipse/jetty/policy/JettyPolicy.html#114), it appears a `null` `CodeSource` reflects that the class has *global* permissions.

> ```
> // 1) if protection domain codesource is null, it is the global permissions (grant {})
> ```

This behavior is documented in the specification of [`ClassLoader.defineClass`](http://goo.gl/yVP5a), so it isn't arbitrary ;-)

> This method assigns a default `ProtectionDomain` to the newly defined class. The `ProtectionDomain` is effectively granted the same set of permissions returned when `Policy.getPolicy().getPermissions(new CodeSource(null, null))` is invoked. The default domain is created on the first invocation of `defineClass`, and re-used on subsequent invocations.

---

Actually,  looking closer, I believe this is the work of [`SecureClassLoader.defineClass`](http://goo.gl/MYFh1)...

> If a non-`null` `CodeSource` is supplied a `ProtectionDomain` is constructed and associated with the class being defined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like getLocation() returns a URL representing the source of the code being loaded. But this isn't always meaningful. What do you do for standard libraries and code local to the machine? The first and probably the second would have to return null.

Comment: Well, the first isn't null in this case because it is being loaded from an external URL.

Comment: Sorry I don't know then. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: No, thank you for trying! I think it would be better as a comment though. :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure what exactly you're trying to get at here, but won't the jvm parameter:

```
-verbose:class
```

already do what you're doing here?

> ```
> [Loaded sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
> [Loaded java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
> [Loaded java.nio.ByteBuffer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
> [Loaded java.nio.HeapByteBuffer from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
> [Loaded java.nio.Bits from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
> [Loaded java.nio.ByteOrder from C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]
> ```

If this is all you're doing, there's not a need to create an agent for it, though it's not clear to me what else you might be trying to do other than this.